# What is the correct order of adjectives in the sentence below?

Tags: sentence-construction, adjective-order

Are adjective put in correct order?

> Do you need a **profitable** **online** **work-from-home** job?

Also, I’d like to know if I use the sentence as a title, am I allowed to remove the word “do”?

Comment: Do you really ***need*** the word "profitable" there? (is *anyone* interested in "non-profitable" jobs?). And since virtually all "work-from-home" jobs will be ***online*** (and that's where your target readership will probably be reading your advert anyway), you probably don't need to specify that either. But syntactically speaking, your sequence as proposed is fine.

Comment: thanks for your answer.

Comment: There's more that *could* be said - but we're at the level of "stylistic choice" here, and I doubt all native speakers would agree on the relevant factors. To my mind, it's perfectly idiomatic to "promote" ***any*** of your adjectival elements to the first position - and the one you put first is the one that gets primary emphasis (perhaps further bolstered by being transcribed in **bold** and/or *italics*). But the order of the remaining two elements might be tricky (because many native speakers wouldn't want to string all three of these elements together in ***any*** such sequence).

Comment: I thought about my sentence and I found that you are right. The word "online" is not really necessary here. so I removed it.
Just one more question. Am I allowed to remove the word “do” if i use the question as a title in my article?

Comment: You're "allowed" to do whatever you like in titles, headlines, catchphrases, advertising slogans, etc. My guess is that most advertising copywriters probably *wouldn't* bother with the standard "verb-subject inversion before question" syntax here. But consider the US ad campaign [***Got Milk**?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Got_Milk%3F) (no ***Have you...***), which according to that linked Wikipedia article, *almost didn't turn into an advertising campaign, [because] people at Goodby, Silverstein [the big ad agencies] "thought it was **lazy**, not to mention **grammatically incorrect**"*